# Functions that hasn't any root

Tags: functional-equations

we say that a function like $f:X \to X$ has root if exists a function like $g:X\to X$ that for every $x \in X$:
$$f(x) = g(g(x))$$

what is a necessary and sufficient condition for $f$ that it has a root.

for example the below function hasn't any root:

$$f:\mathbb{Z}_4 \to \mathbb{Z}_4$$
$$f(x) = x+1$$

Comment: A neccesary condition is that the composition of $f$ and $g$ commute.

Comment: ok, it is true. but we want just some conditions on $f$.@frog

Comment: Lemma 1 and 2 from [this paper](http://yaroslavvb.com/papers/rice-when.pdf) should give you some ideas.